# Storing return value in variable isn't giving me the same thing as calling the function by name

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a memory game using only vanilla javascript and the function below is supposed to store all open cards in an Nodelist, that I want to turn into an array later. When I call the function, using selected(); I get all of the cards I clicked on, but when I use the variable selectedCards, it only gives me the first card I clicked on. Why is that?

```
function selected () {
let select = [];
//class = 'open' turns the card over in grid when clicked
if (document.querySelectorAll('.open')) {
    select.push((document.querySelectorAll('.open')));
};
return select;
};
let selectedCards = selected();
```

Eventually I want to use the function below to check if the cards in the selectedCards array match.

```
function isMatch() {
   if (selectedCards[0].type === selectedCards[1].type) {
     function matched(){
       selectedCards[0].classList.add("match");
       selectedCards[1].classList.add("match");
       selectedCards[0].classList.remove("show", "open");
       selectedCards[1].classList.remove("show", "open");
       selectedCards = [];
     }
   }
};
```

I've only been learning javascript for around 2 weeks not, so this might now even be possible with the functions I've created? I dunno, any help is greatly appreciated though!

Comment: `selectedCards[0]` will be the `HTMLCollection` returned by `document.querySelectorAll('.open')` ... so, there's only one element in the returned array, which will be an array-like HTMLcollection ... perhaps you just wish to `return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.open'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the NodeList to Array like this.Here you can see both `selected()` and `selectedCards` returns the same result.

```js
function selected () {
let select = [];
//class = 'open' turns the card over in grid when clicked
let sel = document.querySelector('.open');
  
if (sel) {
    select= [].slice.call(sel.querySelectorAll('.inner'));
};
return select;
};
let selectedCards = selected();
console.log(selected());
console.log(selectedCards);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="open">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works, but why am I only getting one item in the array when I use the variable selectedCards compared to calling the function selected();?

Comment: @trqkkr see my edit. I get same result for both *function* and *variable with function expression*

Comment: thanks, I had to fiddle with some things, but got it work!